# how to add an icon to an UIActionSheet button?

Tags: iphone

I hope to know how to add an icon to an UIActionSheet button?

I checked some document but no result.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: I cannot find any documented way to do it, so there is no way to do it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to do this with the current SDK.

Comment: This is not true. It has been possible since at least 4.3, and still works on iOS 7.

Comment: You are a true hero, sir, downvoting a 2 1/2 year old correct answer to promote you own. Although your answer gives a working solution, it is not part of the documented SDK, but rather a work around for a private method. It *might* break anytime - be it likely or unlikely.

Comment: @elko: Apologies. You are correct on both accounts.

Answer (score 4):

Although there is no API, it is a simple property you can change.

You can access each UIButton image like so:

```
SEL buttonsSEL = @selector(buttons);
if([yourUIActionSheet respondsToSelector:buttonsSEL]) {
    NSString *buttonsSel = NSStringFromSelector(buttonsSEL);

    [[[yourUIActionSheet valueForKey:buttonsSel objectAtIndex:yourIndex]
        setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ...
}
```

where

- yourUIActionSheet is a UIActionSheet*
- yourIndex is an int representing the button index, starting at 0

Comment: Thanks, this works, but is this legal or would the app be rejected?

Comment: Yes. Legal since post day. Will work until the last iOS 7, inclusive. Won't work after that.